# WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED! Chrome Secure Shell App extension

Tags: google-chrome, ssh

```
Loading NaCl plugin... done.
Connecting to user@172.27.0.31...
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@    WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!     @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
IT IS POSSIBLE THAT SOMEONE IS DOING SOMETHING NASTY!
Someone could be eavesdropping on you right now (man-in-the-middle attack)!
It is also possible that a host key has just been changed.
The fingerprint for the ECDSA key sent by the remote host is
SHA256:C11asdfasdfxY6asdfasdfIUfadsfasdRB4.
Please contact your system administrator.
Add correct host key in /.ssh/known_hosts to get rid of this message.
Offending ECDSA key in /.ssh/known_hosts:21
ECDSA host key for 172.27.0.31 has changed and you have requested strict checking.
Host key verification failed.
NaCl plugin exited with status code 255.
(R)econnect, (C)hoose another connection, or E(x)it?
```

This error is related to Chrome Secure Shell App extension.

This error may happen if you are under man in the middle attack or due to certificate change on the server side.

Previous fix to this was to delete local entry from known hosts by using Chrome console:

```
term_.command.removeKnownHostByIndex(21)
```

But produces error:

```
VM237:1 Uncaught TypeError: term_.command.removeKnownHostByIndex is not a function
    at <anonymous>:1:15
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Now (my chrome Version 85.0.4183.83 (Official Build) (64-bit)) an entry can be deleted manually in extension settings. 3 dots (chrome right upper corner) > More tools > Extensions > Secure Shell App Details > Extensions > options > SSH Files > Delete specific entry (whole row) in ~/.ssh/known_hosts

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's now 3dots>Extensions>Manage Extensions

Answer (score 1):

now that the app is discouraged in favour of the extension,
in the top-left corner of the terminal you may click the icon,
and delve into terminal settings and SSH.

~/.ssh/known_hosts is there.

good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Now it looks like the easiest way (on windows) is to right click on the extension icon and select options.  The 2 options above weren't working for me..

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cbpej.png)

Comment: a link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: add [context around the link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).